# Procedure runs,but doesn't do anything

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a little problem with running a certain procedure in MariaDB.
The funny thing is that when i run the procedure,it doesn't show any errors,but unfortunately it doesn't do anything.
And I can't simply find what's wrong.

Guys please help.Thx

Query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `p_tun_removal`(IN `GeoTerID` INT)
       LANGUAGE SQL
       NOT DETERMINISTIC
       CONTAINS SQL
       SQL SECURITY DEFINER

    BEGIN

    DECLARE @done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE @CurrentVersion INT;
    DECLARE @CorrectVersion INT;
    DECLARE @BeginVersion INT;

    DECLARE cur1
       CURSOR FOR
       SELECT Distinct(Version) 
       FROM geo_patch 
       WHERE TerID = GeoTerID AND Version >= BeginVersion;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    declare exit handler for sqlexception 

    begin
       rollback;
       resignal;
    end;

    CREATE Temporary TABLE `tunnel_temp` (
       `ID` INT NOT NULL
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB;


    insert into tunnel_temp ( ID ) (
       SELECT ID from geo_patch 
       WHERE Version in ( select Version from geo_patch where Substance = 0 ) and TerID = GeoTerID
    );


    SET @BeginVersion = ( SELECT Version from geo_patch where ID = ( SELECT ID from tunnel_temp limit 1 ) ) - 1 ;
    SET @CorrectVersion = @BeginVersion;
    IF (@CorrectVersion < 2) THEN
       SET @CorrectVersion = 2;
    END IF;

     START TRANSACTION;

       DELETE FROM geo_patch where ID in ( Select ID from tunnel_temp );

       open cur1;
       version_loop: LOOP
       FETCH cur1 into @CurrentVersion;

       IF done THEN
          LEAVE version_loop;
       END IF;

       UPDATE geo_patch SET Version = @CorrectVersion WHERE Version = @CurrentVersion;
       SET CorrectVersion = CorrectVersion + 1;

       END LOOP;
       close cur1;

    COMMIT;

    UPDATE terrain_blocks SET GeoVersion = ( select Version from geo_patch where TerID = GeoTerID order by Version desc limit 1 ) WHERE ID = GeoTerID;

    drop temporary table if exists tunnel_temp;

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )`, use a `JOIN` instead.
- Try to avoid cursors by doing the entire operation in a single statement.